JWT token associated to a k8s service account
Look at this yaml manifest:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: myserviceaccount
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myserviceaccount-token
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: myserviceaccount
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token

I apply this manifest on my k8s cluster:
$ kubectl apply -f myserviceaccount.yaml

When I try this command:
$ kubectl -n default get service account/myserviceaccount

-> I see 0 secrets count
I should see at least 1 secret for myserviceaccount-token.
Why do I not see this secret ?
Thanks

As per this Medium blog by LU Andy


From Kubernetes Version 1.24, the default tokens created by Kubernetes for SAs are no longer long-lived. Only the  service account
resource is created.
Legacy SA tokens are long-lived, meaning those tokens NEVER expire, unless you delete the service accounts then the Kubernetes Token
controller will delete all corresponding SA token Secret objects.


As per this Github Link 

The LegacyServiceAccountTokenNoAutoGeneration feature gate is beta,
and enabled by default. When enabled, Secret API objects containing
service account tokens are no longer auto-generated for every
ServiceAccount. Use the TokenRequest API to acquire service account
tokens, or if a non-expiring token is required, create a Secret API
object for the token controller to populate with a service account
token by following this guide. (#108309, @zshihang)

Since you are using a version 1.24 or above, that's the reason myserviceaccount-token won’t be automatically generated. There are many approaches to acquire a token for your service account in k8s 1.24 or above. You need to use one of the methods described in the above Medium blog to request a token.
